# Falha de segmentação

Tags: c++, string, memória

Criei uma classe para exibir uma *string* no terminal, mas além de exibir a *string*, também, exibe a seguinte mensagem: "falha de segmentação". Depurei com GDB, mas não consegui resolver o erro. Segue o código abaixo:

```
#ifndef CONNECTION_H
#define CONNECTION_H

#include<string>
#include<iostream>

using std::string;

class Connection {

public:

   Connection();
  ~Connection(); 

  string conexao;
  string getConexao();

};

#endif // CONNECTION_H




#include"teste.h"

Connection::Connection() 
{
  conexao = "sete de setembro";
}


string Connection::getConexao()

{  
  std::cout << conexao << std::endl;
}


Connection::~Connection()
{

}





#include "teste.h"

int main(void)
{

Connection con;
con.getConexao();

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você criou um método que retorna uma `string`, mas não retornou nada. Então causa um erro.

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

using std::string;
using namespace std;

class Connection {
public:
    Connection();
    string conexao;
    string getConexao();
};

Connection::Connection() {
    conexao = "sete de setembro";
}

string Connection::getConexao() {  
    cout << conexao << endl;
    return conexao;
}

int main(void) {
    Connection con;
    con.getConexao();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/4zQ5eI). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/krslwqww-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Memory/SegFault.cpp).

Comment: Bigown, 
Mesmo sem o retorno a mensagem de erro continua sendo exibida.

Comment: Mas precisa do retorno. Eu te mostrei funcionando. Se o seu código tem algo diferente, eu não tenho como ajudar. Só posso falar do que estou vendo. Se transformar em `void`também funciona, mas seria estranho uma função que começa com `get` retornar nada. http://ideone.com/KTs5zg

Comment: Eu coloquei get para se referir a uma função de retorno mesmo.
Não sabia que o compilador iria entender o get, pois achei ser opcional.

Comment: @L.Hora Uma pista de que o problema era esse é o alerta que aparece no seu compilador quando você liga todos os alertas. No GCC, isso pode ser feito com -Wall e dá a seguinte mensagem: `warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
 }` , que significa que está faltando retornar alguma coisa na sua função.

Como o colega @bigown disse, get é meio que um padrão para funções que retornam valores. Não use para funções que imprimem coisas.

Comment: Entendi,
Obrigado a Bigown e a você Pablo pelos esclarecimentos.